# How to delete entities in (multithreaded) transactional Spring/JPA

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

Assume there is a service component, taking use of a `CrudRepository` of `Book` entities. Assume one of the methods of the service should be transactional, and should (among other things) delete one entity from the database with transactional semantics (i.e. should the delete be impossible to perform, all effects should be rolled-back).

Roughly,

```
@Component
public class TraService {
    @Autowired
    BookRepo repo;

    @Transactional
    public void removeLongest() {
        //some repo.find's and business logic --> Book toDel
        repo.delete(toDel);
    }
}
```

Now this should work in a multithreaded context, e.g. in a Spring MVC. For simplicity I launch 2 threads, each on a task provided with a reference to the `TraService` bean. Logs show, that indeed two `EntityManager`s are created and bound to the respective threads. However, as the first thread is successful with `delete`, the other throws

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1;
```

from which I do not know how to recover (i.e. I suspect the rollback is not complete, and the code the thread was supposed to execute after calling the transactional method will not be executed). Worker's code:

```java
public void run() {
   service.removeLongest();  //transactional
   System.out.println("Code progressing really well " + Thread.currentThread());  //not executed on thread with exception
}
```

How do we properly handle such transactional `delete`s in Spring/JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** The correct behaviour on optimistic lock exceptions is **Catch the exception and Retry**.

**Long answer:** Optimistic locking is a mutex strategy that assume that

from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

> multiple transactions can frequently complete without interfering with each other

Optimistic locking exist mainly because of performances, and is usually implemented with a field that takes into account each modification with a `version` counter. If during a transaction the `version` counter changes, that means that a concurrent modification is happening and that cause the exception to be thrown.

Pessimistic locking will instead prevent any possible concurrent modification, easier to manage, but with worse performances.

Comment: Thanks for OCC. What remains: do you know, if catching the `JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException` exception where the outermost transactional method is called guarantees, that whole rollback was complete (so: ACID)?

Comment: If your method is annotated with @Transactional, any exception thrown a that level will rollback the transaction.